# Why is google distance matrix not accepting my variables as locations?

Tags: php, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to pass some html form input through google distance matrix api. I have put them into variables and replaced the spaces with "+" signs. When I echo the variables they are perfect. When I hard code those variable values the api returns the distance, but it returns nothing when I use the variable representations.

```
<?php

$start = $_POST["origin"];
$end = $_POST["destination"];


$value = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '+', $start));

echo $value;

$value2 = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '+', $end));

echo $value2;

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?   
origins=$value&destinations=$value2&mode=driving&language=English- 
en&key=$key"';
$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array
echo $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

?>
```

Comment: you are using single quotes around the url but appear to have php variables in the string - they need to be unquoted / escaped or use double quotes around entire url. ie: `$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={$value}&destinations={$value2}&mode=driving&language=English- 
en&key={$key}";`

Comment: And there are spaces after `json?` in the url above

Comment: @RamRaider Hey thank you! It's working great now. Go ahead and throw it into a post so I can mark it as answer

Comment: @RaimRaider there are not. Just appears that way due to the forced next line by stack

Comment: ok - thought as much but better to point it out anyway just in case. good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: @RamRaider thanks again. Have a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the use / misuse of single quotes when working with PHP variables. If you use single quotes then variables within must be unquoted / escaped so that they are interpreted correctly. Perhaps the more favourable approach is to use double quotes around the entire string/url - use curly braces if necessary to ensure certain types of variables are processed properly ( ie: using an array variable `{$arr['var']}` )

For the situation above the following ought to work - shown on one line deliberately to highlight that there are now no spaces in the url.

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={$value}&destin‌​ations={$value2}&mode=driving&language=English-en&key={$key}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $url variable is being set using literal quotes (single quotes).

If you want to use variables inside a string you need to use double quotes, otherwise you need to concatenate.

I also see an extra double quote hanging on the end of your url string as well, try this with corrections:

```
<?php

$start = urlencode($_POST["origin"]);
$end = urlencode($_POST["destination"]);

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?   
origins={$start}&destinations={$end}&mode=driving&language=English- 
en&key=$key";

$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array

echo $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

?>
```